# Unity: Game works in editor but doesn't when built. Does editor code differ from build?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, colors, renderer

I have an issue with my simple game I am creating using Unity engine. In this game the player can pick up and interact with objects. What I am doing is that when player is looking at an object and is within range , the object changes color. This works fine in editor and no errors are thrown.

However when the game is built everything seems to work until I look at the object and try to interact with it. The color changes to pink as if there were no material/texture. And when I look away it stays pink, when it should turn to original color.Also no errors are thrown in debug.

**In the Editor:**

Before looking at object

[image]

After looking at object

[image]

**In a Built game:**

Before looking at object

[image]

After looking at object

[image]

- output_log.txt doesn't have any errors.
- Unity is up to date (5.6.1f1)
- No errors in Editor debug as well as built game debug.
- I read somewhere that Assembly-UnityScript.dll should be present in game folder,but it is missing from mine. But that answer was from a few years ago.
  And other scripts seem to be working(walking,triggers,sounds,etc).

Code:

Interaction that calls change of color:

```
    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward), out hit, raycastDistance, layerMask))
    {


        if (hit.collider.tag=="Computer") {
            hit.collider.GetComponentInChildren<Image> ().color = Color.cyan;

            return;
        }

        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * hit.distance, Color.yellow);

        if (lastHit != null) {

            if (lastHit != GameObject.Find (hit.collider.name)) {
                lastHit.GetComponent<ManipulateColor> ().setDefaultColor ();
            }
        }

        lastHit = GameObject.Find (hit.collider.name);
        lastHit.GetComponent<ManipulateColor> ().setColor ();

        interactionText.text = lastHit.GetComponent<Interactable> ().interactionText;
        interactionText.enabled = true;

        canInteract = true;

    }
    else
    {
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * raycastDistance, Color.white);

        if (lastHit != null) {
            lastHit.GetComponent<ManipulateColor> ().setDefaultColor ();
        }

        interactionText.enabled = false;
        canInteract = false;
    }
```

// Color changing class:

```
public Color colorToSet = Color.green;

private Color defaultColor;

private List<Color> childrenColors = new List<Color>();
private List<Color> colorListToUse = new List<Color> ();

private Renderer rend;

private bool hasChildren = false;
private bool parentHasRender = false;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {


    if (gameObject.transform.childCount > 0) {
        hasChildren = true;
        if (gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer> ()!=null) {
            rend = gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer> ();
            childrenColors.Add (rend.materials [0].color);
            parentHasRender = true;
        } 

        foreach (Transform child in gameObject.transform) {


            if (child.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer> ()!=null) {

                rend = child.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer> ();
                childrenColors.Add (rend.materials [0].color);
            }

        }

    } else {
        rend = gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer> ();
        defaultColor = rend.materials[0].color;
    }


    colorListToUse = childrenColors;

}

public void setColor(){




    if (hasChildren) {
        if (parentHasRender) {
            rend = gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer> ();
            rend.materials[0].shader = Shader.Find ("_Color");
            rend.materials[0].SetColor ("_Color", colorToSet);


            rend.materials[0].shader = Shader.Find ("Specular");
            rend.materials[0].SetColor ("_SpecColor", colorToSet);
        }


        foreach (Transform child in gameObject.transform) {
            if (child.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer> ()!=null) {
                rend = child.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer> ();
                rend.materials[0].shader = Shader.Find ("_Color");
                rend.materials[0].SetColor ("_Color", colorToSet);



                rend.materials[0].shader = Shader.Find ("Specular");
                rend.materials[0].SetColor ("_SpecColor", colorToSet);
            }



        }

    } else {
        rend.materials[0].shader = Shader.Find("_Color");
        rend.materials[0].SetColor ("_Color", colorToSet);


        rend.materials[0].shader = Shader.Find("Specular");
        rend.materials[0].SetColor ("_SpecColor", colorToSet);
    }

}

public void setDefaultColor(){



    if (hasChildren) {
        if (parentHasRender) {

            rend.materials[0].shader = Shader.Find("_Color");
            rend.materials[0].SetColor ("_Color", colorListToUse[0]);


            rend.materials[0].shader = Shader.Find("Specular");
            rend.materials[0].SetColor ("_SpecColor", colorListToUse[0]);
            colorListToUse.RemoveAt (0);
        }


        foreach (Transform child in gameObject.transform) {
            if (child.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer> ()!=null) {
                rend = child.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer> ();
                rend.materials[0].shader = Shader.Find ("_Color");
                rend.materials[0].SetColor ("_Color", colorListToUse[0]);



                rend.materials[0].shader = Shader.Find ("Specular");
                rend.materials[0].SetColor ("_SpecColor", colorListToUse[0]);
            }
        }


    } else {
        rend = gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer> ();
        rend.materials[0].shader = Shader.Find("_Color");
        rend.materials[0].SetColor ("_Color", defaultColor);


        rend.materials[0].shader = Shader.Find("Specular");
        rend.materials[0].SetColor ("_SpecColor", defaultColor);

    }


    colorListToUse = childrenColors;
}
```

Solved:

Removing all Shader.Find and SetColor, and instead just using rend.materials[0].color = colorToSet solved the issue;

Comment: What's the name the shader that object is using? Select the material is is using, post screenshot of it's Inspector tab settings. This will help troubleshoot your issue

Comment: Please don't change the title to `Solved`. With accepting an answer the question will already be recognized as solved

Comment: Ok,sorry I am new to this site :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all

```
rend.materials[0].shader = Shader.Find("_Color");
rend.materials[0].SetColor ("_Color", colorToSet);


rend.materials[0].shader = Shader.Find("Specular");
rend.materials[0].SetColor ("_SpecColor", colorToSet);
```

would be quite useless since you overwrite the `materials[0].shader` in line 3 and than only change the `SpecColor` of this new shader. This makes lines 1+2 redundant / effectless.

---

Than to your question: Yes the build behaves a bit different than the editor. In a build the project is stripped of most of the Assets/Scripts etc. if they are never referenced (=> apparently never used).

From [Shader.Find](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Shader.Find.html)

> Note that a shader might be not included into the player build if nothing references it! In that case, Shader.Find will work only in the editor, and will result in pink "missing shader" materials in the player build. Because of that, it is advisable to use shader references instead of finding them by name. To make sure a shader is included into the game build, do either of:
>
> 1) reference it from some of the materials used in your scene,
>
> 2) add it under "Always Included Shaders" list in ProjectSettings/Graphics or
>
> 3) put shader or something that references it (e.g. a Material) into a "Resources" folder.

---

But actually it seems to me that you don't really want to change the `Shader` of the material in runtime but rather the color(s).

So instead of

```
rend.materials[0].shader = Shader.Find("_Color");
rend.materials[0].SetColor ("_Color", colorListToUse[0]);
```

you should just use

```
rend.materials[0].color = colorToSet;
```

to change the color of a material. see also [Material.color](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material-color.html)

If you have only one material assigned you could also simply use

```
rend.material.color = colorToSet;
```

---

If you than still should need to also set a`SpecColor` you should already in the Editor set the according materials to Specular and than you can still use

```
rend.materials[0].SetColor ("_SpecColor", colorToSet);
```

Comment: Some of my objects have few materials assigned so I only select the first one. I will try this when I'm at the pc.

Comment: I'm glad to help! Please feel free to accept the answer if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

Remove all [Shader.Find(“...”)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Shader.Find.html) calls, since it does try to load a shader with that name, which does not exist and cause unity to show the beloved pink fallback shader.

Comment: Did you try this?

Comment: No i have not. why are you asking?

Comment: remove them and than what?

Comment: Recompile and test again

Comment: Yeah but OP's goal is to change the color .. so if you remove the line that does it so far I'ld say you should replace it atleast with something right?

Comment: @JeanLuc that was directed to OP. I'm asking if he tried tweaking the `.Find` calls per your answer.

Comment: @derHugo the only issue was the lines with Shader.Find() everything else was fine